# HRESULT E_FAIL in UnsafeNativeMethods.IWebBrowser2.Navigate2

Tags: c#, winforms, vsto

We developed a complex application in .NET 3.5 inside Office 2007. In some Forms we use the WebBrowser control to navigate to our HTML pages. The problem is that on some machines when the control invoke the "Navigate" method it raises an exception "error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component".

From the stack trace we note that the exception come from the WebBrowser control when invoking the Navigate method:

```
 in System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IWebBrowser2.Navigate2
(Object& URL, Object& flags, Object& targetFrameName, Object& postData,
Object& headers)
  in System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.PerformNavigate2(Object& URL, Object&
flags, Object& targetFrameName, Object& postData, Object& headers)
  in System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.PerformNavigateHelper(String
urlString, Boolean newWindow, String targetFrameName, Byte[] postData,
String headers)
  in System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.set_Url(Uri value)
  in System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.set_DocumentStream(Stream value)
  in System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.set_DocumentText(String value)
```

PCs are VISTA with IE8 and Office 2007 Service Pack 2. We use Visual Studio 2010 and VSTO 3.0.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I have observed this behaviour when Webpages include JavaScript code that closes the window.

It's simple to reproduce, open an HTML file like the following in your WebBrowser Control:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:window.close();">close</a>
<!-- or a version without further user interaction -->
<a href="javascript:window.open('','_self').close();">close without request</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Click on the link and afterwards navigate your WebBrowser Control to another Url.

This will cause the `Navigate2` function to throw the Exception `error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component`, because the underlying ActiveX component was disposed when closing the window.