# How fix HRESULT E_FAIL?

Tags: c#, navigation, hresult

I'm working in a wind form which open a link in a selected browser iexplorer, chrome or edge I use SHDocVw.IWebBroser2.navigate2(url, 0x08000) to open iexplorer in a new tab but in some times this line gets this error System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Error HRESULT E_FAIL
I searched about but... I don't understand
Can someone help me please? i'm a beginner learning.

Comment: Does it depend on the site you are navigating to? Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009820/hresult-e-fail-in-unsafenativemethods-iwebbrowser2-navigate2

Comment: Why can't you use the actual [WebBrowser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser?view=net-5.0) control?